# Cannot find library file when compiling with Cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am building / compiling a Cython project:

**setup.caller.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name = 'test app',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = cythonize([
        Extension(
            'caller',
            ['caller.pyx', 'foo.cpp'],
            language='c++',
            extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11'],
            library_dirs=['/usr/lib/bar'],
            libraries=['libbar'],
            include_dirs=['/usr/include/baz']
        )
    ])
)
```

But when I build / compile I get an error:

```
$ python setup.caller.py build_ext --inplace
...
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibbar
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-g++' failed with exit status 1
```

I checked, and "libbar.so" is in "/usr/lib/bar".  I am compiling on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be just `bar` not `libbar`, linkers know to add the `lib` prefix and whatever suffix is needed (`.a` or `.so`).